# how to read out a string type property corresponding to the object selected in listbox control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, text-to-speech

**Situation** : I have a `listbox` control in MainPage.xaml.cs . Its `ItemSource` is set to a collection called `Problems` of type `ItemViewModel` class instantiated in contructor of `MainViewModel` class . Now when a user taps on a item in listbox control , he is navigated to page1.xaml , page1.xaml.cs has the following logic to know which object of Problems collection was selected .

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataContext == null)
        {
            string selectedIndex = "";
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
            {
                int index = int.Parse(selectedIndex);
                DataContext = App.ViewModel.Problems[index];
            }
        }
    }
```

Then page1.xaml would display properties corresponding to the selected object .

I have a property `Name` of type string defined in `ItemViewModel` class which i am trying to read out in page1.xaml, by placing the following logic in `speakButton` event handler located in Page1.xaml.cs :

```
private async void speakButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        await synth.SpeakTextAsync(App.ViewModel.Problems[0].Name);
    }
```

**Problem** : The problem is that the `speakButton` is reading out value of `Name` property of object that is at 0 position in Problems collection ,  what i want is that it should read out the value of Name property corresponding to the object that is selected by user , can anyone provide a logic for this ?

Comment: What has this got to do with backwards compatibility?

Comment: If I just read the title, I can guarantee the following: any Windows Phone 8.0 app will run on Windows Phone 8.1. That doesn't mean that any code that worked in a Windows Phone 8.0 project will work in 8.1, because they made the move from Silverlight to Winodows RT which necessarily fored them to rename / replace some namespaces

Comment: Sorry guyz , i mistakenly gave the wrong title , i was framing another question

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable index as a public property , so that it can be accessed by all the members of page1 class .

```
public int index { get; set; }
```

Next , use this logic to retrieve the index of the selected object :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataContext == null)
        {
            string selectedIndex = "";
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
            {
                index = int.Parse(selectedIndex);
                DataContext = App.ViewModel.Problems[index];
            }
        }
    }
```

After this , in the event handler of `speakButton` write the following code :

```
private async void speakButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        await synth.SpeakTextAsync(App.ViewModel.Problems[index].Name);
    }
```

Now when speak button is clicked the value of Name property corresponding to the object selected will be read out .